# Replace newline (\n) except last of each line

Tags: sed

my input is split into multiple lines. I want it to output in a single line.

For example Input is :

```
1|23|ABC
DEF
GHI
newline
newline
2|24|PQR
STU
LMN
XYZ
newline
```

Output:

```
1|23|ABC DEF GHI

2|24|PQR STU LMN XYZ
```

Comment: _newline except last of each line_ How do you define a line?

Comment: Does "newline" represent a blank line?  This feels like a job for `awk` with an unset RS, but it's difficult to say without an accurate description of the input

Comment: Actually the data  should be "1|23|ABC DEF GHI\n". but when i tried BCP the data truncated into multiple line(s). the "newline" are blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is one for awk:

```
$ awk -v RS="" -F"\n" '{$1=$1}1' file
```

Output:

```
1|23|ABC DEF GHI
2|24|PQR STU LMN XYZ
```

Comment: this gives one line

Comment: @Ben Maybe, if you have DOS line endings (\r\n) instead of just \n.